# How to generate vector arrows that conforms to a raster slope layer?

Tags: r, python-2.7, arcgis, r-raster

I would like to generate vector arrows that conform to the topography/slope of a raster dataset of a river catchment area.

I have created a Fishnet grid of points in ArcGIS and I would like to create a single arrow for each point of a set length that will follow the shape of the slope i.e. follow the path of least resistance, the line will follow progressively small numbers in a 3 x 3 grid.

I think I can generate the vector arrows using vector plot. Is it possible to achieve the lines conforming to the raster?

UPDATE: I have ~200,000 lines that I generated from a grid of points. I am going to turn these into a raster using R and set it to the same resolution as my slope raster.

Any ideas on how to layer the raster lines on the slope so I can get the lines to follow the lowest values of the slope?

Answer (score 0):

This is for display/mapping purposes only? Use a DEM or TIN and display your arrow lines in ArcScene.

EDIT: given your update about your data and software not working-

**Try this:**

**1)** Make a raster surface covering the extent of your data with a cell size of 100m (or smaller or larger if that doesn't suit)

**2)** Convert that raster to a polygon layer e.g. 'area_grid100m'

**3)** Do a spatial join and assign all points a polygon cell id from one of the unique id fields in 'area_grid100m'

**4)** Use `Summarize` to get the mean lat/long of the start points and mean lat/long of the end points for each polygon. `Summarize` on the polygon id field and get select mean for both the lat and long fields

**5)** Add summary table to ArcMap, right click and select `Display XY Data` (set X Field as longitude and y Field as latitude). Right right the result and select `Data` > `Export Data` to make it permanent. You will now have two points per 'area_grid100m' cell.

**5)** Recreate your lines using this new file, which will give you one line per cell

If the res is not small enough, make the 'area_grid' cells smaller.

Comment: So far I can only create straight vector arrows. I have tried using ArcScene to display the arrows but there is a few  other layers that go with the arrows and the high resolution of the data makes the program clunky and it keeps crashing. These arrows are providing paddock scale resolution.